# Why do i have two different histograms in R

Tags: r

I came out two different histograms by making small changes of my codes. But I don't know the reason of that. Please help, thank you in advance!

First:

```
niter=1e5
W100=rep(0,niter)
for(i in 1:niter)
{
  W=cumsum(sample(c(1,-1),100,replace = TRUE))

  W100[i]=W[100]

}
hist(W100,breaks=100)
```

Histogram:

[image]

Second:

```
niter=1e5
W=rep(0,niter)
for(i in 1:niter)
{
  W=cumsum(sample(c(1,-1),100,replace = TRUE))

  W[i]=W[100]

}
hist(W,breaks=100)
```

Histogram:

[image]

By adding 100 after the W, there will come out the different histograms. Why?

Comment: do `set.seed(some number)` before `sample`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried to set seed. But still have two different histograms

Comment: in both of your for loops, put `set.seed(i)` before `W=...`

Comment: I tried again, still have that problem  : (

Comment: The final line of the loop code in the first instance is saving values to a vector that is not being changed at every loop iteration, whereas you change W before assigning a value to W[i]. In the second loop you are wiping out all the earlier assignments with the sampling code and only get  the results of the last sample for 99 of 100 locations of W.

Comment: Your answer solved my problem. Thank you so much!

Comment: @42-, if you post your comment an the answer we can close this question.